# Generating a pure (or flat) binary

Tags: macos, assembly, operating-system, gnu-assembler

How can you generate a flat binary that will run directly on the CPU?
That is, without an Operating System; also called free standing environment code (see [What is the name for a program running directly without an OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274513/what-is-the-name-for-a-program-running-directly-without-an-os)).

I've noticed that the assembler I'm using, `as` from the OS-X developer tools bundle, keeps generating Mach-O files, and not flat binaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482059/how-to-compile-an-assembly-file-to-a-raw-binary-like-dos-com-format-with-gnu

Comment: Before I answer, tell us what you plan to do with this pure/flat binary?

Comment: @jensbjörnhager I use AT&T syntax on a UNIX system; seeing as the only answer there was to use another assembler I think this question is worth asking in a different manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828631/how-to-generate-plain-binaries-like-nasm-f-bin-with-the-gnu-gas-assembler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. You get the *linker* to produce a flat (pure) binary. To do that, you have to write a linker script file with `OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)`. If memory serves, you also need to specify something about how the sections are merged, but I don't remember any of the details.

Comment: any idea how to apply a linker script? my man page is not showing me the option under `ld`. (Mac OS 10.6)

Comment: @Hawken: At least with normal versions of ld, its `-T <filename>` or `--script=<filename>`.

Comment: `ld: unknown option: -T` this doesn't bode well, but I'll stick it under another question I think.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way I've done it. Using the linker that comes with the XCode Command Line Tools, you can combine object files using:

```
ld code1.o code2.o -o code.bin -r -U start
```

The `-r` asks `ld` to just combine object files together without making a library, `-U` tells `ld` to ignore the missing definition of `_start` (which would normally be provided by the C stdlib).

This creates a binary which still has some header bytes, but this is easily identified with

```
otool -l code.bin
```

Look for the `__text` section in the output:

```
Section
  sectname __text
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000
      size 0x0000003b
    offset 240
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 300
    nreloc 1
     flags 0x80000400
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
```

Note the offset (which you can confirm by comparing the output of `otool -l` and `hexdump`). We don't want the headers so just use `dd` to copy out the bytes you need:

```
dd if=code.bin of=code_stripped.bin ibs=240 skip=1
```

where I've set the block size to the offset and skipping one block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you necessarily need to do this. Some bootloaders can load more complex executable formats. For example, GRUB can load ELF right off the bat. I'm sure you can somehow get it or some other bootloader to load Mach-O files.

Comment: Hey, Hawken. I saw this question linked to the other one, and was interested to see it. Anyway, I don't think you need to write anything for grub. There is a guide for installing it here: http://wiki.osdev.org/GRUB. Looking at that, I don't think it does support mach-o. It does support ELF, though, and puts the processor in protected mode.

Comment: @Hawken Ohhh.. How do you write GRUB _itself_. Oh, I don't know. :) It's really complicated. Here's a way to write a bootloader: http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/hello-world-boot-loader, but it's nothing like GRUB, it's much, much simpler. And i'm pretty sure it'll only load flat binaries. Loading more complex formats is more difficult.

Comment: In fact, that link doesn't describe a bootloader, but a simple program the displays the string 'Hello World'. There are ones online that load simple binaries, though. I used to tinker with this stuff a lot, and I've used many. If I find one, I'll post a link.

Comment: Awesome, I actually did mean any sort of "free standing environment" (stackoverflow.com/questions/10274513) not just a boot loader.

Comment: Okay, well, that is an example. Also, look at all the great resources on that site ( http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/index ). It has a lot of useful stuff that I think you'll be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the `nasm` assembler -- it has an option to control the output binary format, including `-f bin` for flat binaries.

Note that you can't easily compile C code to flat binaries, since almost any C code will require binary features (like external symbols and relocations) which can't be represented in a flat binary.

Comment: sorry I love AT&T syntax too much to switch to nasm, and I wouldn't trust having all my code run through an intel-at&t converter for every file. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way I know of.

Once I needed to create plain binary file which will be loaded and executed by another program. However, `as` didn't allow me to do that. I tried to use `gobjcopy` to convert object file to raw binary, but it was not able to properly convert code such as this:

```
.quad LinkName2 - LinkName1
```

In binary file produced by `gobjcopy` it looked like

```
.quad 0
```

I've ended up writing special dumping program, which is executable that will save part of the memory on disk:

```
            .set SYS_EXIT, 0x2000001
            .set SYS_READ, 0x2000003
            .set SYS_WRITE, 0x2000004
            .set SYS_OPEN, 0x2000005
            .set SYS_CLOSE, 0x2000006
```

.data
dumpfile:   .ascii "./dump"
            .byte 0
OutputFileDescriptor:   .quad 0

```
        .section __TEXT,__text,regular
        .globl _main
```

_main:

```
        movl $0644, %edx # file mode
        movl $0x601, %esi # O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY
        leaq dumpfile(%rip), %rdi
        movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax
        syscall
        movq %rax, OutputFileDescriptor(%rip)

        movq $EndDump - BeginDump, %rdx
        leaq BeginDump(%rip), %rsi
        movq OutputFileDescriptor(%rip), %rdi
        movl $SYS_WRITE, %eax
        syscall

        movq OutputFileDescriptor(%rip), %rdi
        movl $SYS_CLOSE, %eax
        syscall
```

Done:
            movq %rax, %rdi
            movl $SYS_EXIT, %eax
            syscall

```
        .align 3
```

BeginDump:
            .include "dump.s"
EndDump:
            .quad 0
The code that have to be saved as raw binary file is included in `dump.s`